# How to find which type of error in app/Mage.php line no. 546 in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento, helper

I am getting Magento : `Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Fooman_Helper_Data'` not found in `…/app/Mage.php` on line 546. which code i have to put in this function to get error of which type? please check this code:

```
<?php
public static function helper($name)
{
    $registryKey = '_helper/' . $name;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
       $helperClass = self::getConfig()->getHelperClassName($name);
       self::register($registryKey, new $helperClass);
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please, don't post picture for your code, copy/paste it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you're seeing is the best info you're going to get, but it's something that isn't easy to figure out for first-timers. You're seeing that because Magento can't find a class you're trying to access via the following:

```
Mage::helper("fooman")
```

When it tries to fall back to Mage_*, it means you haven't provided corresponding config.xml to define where the fooman helper is located. Your `Fooman` module should include the following in it's `etc/config.xml` (replacing Namespace_Fooman with your own names):

```
<helpers>
  <fooman>
      <class>Namespace_Fooman_Helper</class>
  </fooman>
</helpers>
```